# Art Game - Force JSON call to be uncached

Tags: php, json

I created a "guess the card art" game for Yu-Gi-Oh! [here](https://db.ygoprodeck.com/artgame/).

Basically it calls my php API which gets a random card every time.

API call: https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v4/artgame.php?format=speed

The API is called through JSON to show the card. The first JSON call is when a format is selected. It will show a card and you can guess. Right/Wrong/Skip causes the next JSON call to activate which brings up the next card.

**Occasionally, the card will remain the same for the initial call and the first subsequent call, as if the call has been cached**. **It only ever happens for the first and subsequent call** but doesn't occuer every time, usually if I clear my cache and try again.

I'm using these cache control methods on the top of my **PHP API file**:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

**My JSON call:**

```
var url = "https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v4/artgame.php"+difficultyformat;

//Get Card Data
jQuery.getJSON(url,
    function(data) {

        jQuery.each(data, function (i, val) {

        jQuery('.imgholder').append('<img src="'+val[0].image_url+'">');            

        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah silly me. I didn't realize `getJSON` has built in caching.

I changed this:

```
//Get Card Data
jQuery.getJSON(url,
    function(data) {

        jQuery.each(data, function (i, val) {

        jQuery('.imgholder').append('<img src="'+val[0].image_url+'">');            

        });
    }
);
```

To This:

```
var url = "https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v4/artgame.php"+difficultyformat;

//Get Card Data
jQuery.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

    jQuery.each(data, function (i, val) {

        jQuery('.imgholder').append('<img src="'+val[0].image_url+'">');

        });
    }
});
```

You can also use the following but it disabled cache globally which I definitely don't want:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```